# Error while starting the audit daemon

Tags: linux, logging, audit

I've already installed audit daemon. Now i tried to start it. This error keeps comming up.

```
Job for auditd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status auditd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

What is this error? And how can i get rid of it?

Now i've also reinstalled the package and still have the same errors. Please help me.

While installing the package,  get a new error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 auditd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is this error?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the error message?

Comment: I ran the `systemctl status auditd.service` and got this `● auditd.service - Security Auditing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-06-11 17:47:21 IST; 21s ago
  Process: 9793 ExecStartPost=/sbin/auditctl -R /etc/audit/audit.rules (code=exi
  Process: 9791 ExecStart=/sbin/auditd -n (code=exited, status=6)
 Main PID: 9791 (code=exited, status=6)
lines 1-6/6 (END)
`

Comment: And when i ran `journalctl -xe` , i got this `Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
      turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
`

Comment: Hi can you try `systemctl status auditd.service -l` to show the full log if there are more output

Comment: This is what i get @Jaay  `auditd.service - Security Auditing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-06-11 18:29:11 IST; 2min 6s
  Process: 17742 ExecStartPost=/sbin/auditctl -R /etc/audit/audit.rules (code=ex
  Process: 17739 ExecStart=/sbin/auditd -n (code=exited, status=6)
 Main PID: 17739 (code=exited, status=6)
`

Answer (score -1):

Run

ls -RZa /var/log/audit

restorecon -vr /var/log/audit

ls -RZa /var/log/audit -- compare difference now

service auditd start  -- start audit service